# Spring bootb absctractmethoderror after hibernate upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

My project use spring boot 1.3.8 and now I have to upgrade hibernate from 4.* to 5.*. When I add dependencies and start project I have error "java.lang.AbstractMethodError" after initialization Datasource bean. What can I do for resolve this problem ?

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ussdDBEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = builder
            .dataSource(ussdDBDataSource())
            .persistenceUnit("ussdDBPersistenceUnit")
            .build();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    emf.setJpaProperties(properties);
    return emf;
}
```

Error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ussdDBEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/intech/kievstar/config/DBUssdConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError`

Comment: You cannot use Hibernate 5 with that version, you will need to upgrade Spring Boot. 1.3 is an ancient version.

Comment: I upgrade my spring boot to 1.4.8 and now I have same problem. AbstractMethodError

Comment: You need someting in the 1.5 or 2.0 range and don't use the latest hibernate version check the spring version for which hibernate version is supported.

Comment: I delete hibernate dependencies. Use only spring boot 1.4.7 hibernate and I see this error again

Comment: Then you must be messing around with other dependencies instead of letting Spring BOot manage them.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of my problem was dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I up verson to 5.0.0.GA, problem was resolved